# Failed to compile. Error: Missing class properties transform

Tags: webpack-2, babeljs

```
Error: Missing class properties transform
```

Test.js:

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
   static defaultProps = {
      color: 'blue',
      text: 'Confirm'
   };
}
```

.babelrc:

```
{
 "presets": ["latest", "react"],
 "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
}
```

package.json:

```
"babel-core": "^6.24.1",
"babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-latest": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rgSj.png)

I don't know whether I should require other modules

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. This site can help you test your code and add presets.[The compiler for JavaScript](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=env%2Creact%2Cstage-0&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=)

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
  "babel-preset-env": "^1.4.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1"
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "env",
    "react",
    "stage-0"
  ]
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        }
      ]
   }
```

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to include the whole stage-0, unless you use a whole lot of stage-0 features (class properties are stage 3, anyway). Otherwise it should suffice to use the class-properties transform babel plugin.    So I'm not sure what a more targeted solution would be (I have the same issue).